# What approach should I use for C# scripting

Tags: c#, scripting, delegates

I'm writing a particle system. (for a game and a particle editor)
In this system there are a 0 to n modifiers.
Those modify the particles in the particle system every frame.

For example you could have a predefined modifier called "GravityModifier" that only does the following to every particle every frame: "particle.Velocity.Y += 9.81" or something like that.

Now I want the user to be able to write additional modifiers at runtime (in the editor).
I would like to be able to just use C# for this.
And since the particle systems are written to JSON files, the custom modifier scripts should be written as sourcecode (maybe base64 encoded) to the file.

--

My question is:
Assume the game wants to load such a particle system file. How do I compile the custom modifiers into executable code?

Another very important thing to consider when answering this question: Note that this will be a particle system for a game. The compiled code will be called more than 3000 times every frame. (mostly at 60fps)
So it's very important that the compiled code doesn't take much longer to execute than other game-functions.
It would be nice to have the modifier scripts compiled into delegates of the form:
    delegate void ModifyParticle(ref Particle p);

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: You may also get some good ideas by searching for this topic on [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).  But, I think it's still a good question for this site.

Comment: I think there are some commercial games (Second Life) that use Mono as a scripting engine: http://www.mono-project.com/Scripting_With_Mono

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,

This is possible and quite simple using the [CSScript library](http://www.csscript.net/).

Comment: Wow thanks. This is exactly what I needed! Specifically the example with LoadMethod(...) & GetStaticMethod()
It works as expected AND provides the same speed as executing a "native" static method! This is perfect.

Answer (score 6):

There is a CTP of the ['Roslyn' C# compiler as a service API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx), where you can execute C# code defined at runtime, such as a REPL etc.  Here is an MSDN Article covering it
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/11/16/the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx

Mono has had this functionality for a while in their [Mono.CSharp library](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=N:Mono.CSharp) so that could be used as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Roslyn](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/11/16/the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx), it's the upcoming (but still very early beta) preview of C# compiler-as-a-service feature in the next .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) instead? See [here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/using-lua-with-c-r2275)  Lua is a fantastically simple scripting language and ideal for scripting in-game actions. Quite alot of iPhone games use Lua in objective-c, and there are a good many that use Lua through .Net too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in compiler from Microsoft in .NET `CSharpCodeProvider`:

How to programmatically compile code using C# compiler:

> The .NET Framework exposes classes that allow you to programmatically
>   access the C# language compiler. This might be useful if you want to
>   write your own code-compiling utilities. This article provides sample
>   code that enables you to compile code from a text source. The
>   application allows you to either just build the executable or build
>   the executable and run it. Any errors that occur during the
>   compilation process are displayed on the form.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

Simply compile and load the binaries when you start the game.

More examples of how to compile dll and load/execute it directly can be found at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx
and its community added content.